# Android SDK not Working inside Eclipse

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, ide, sdk

Using the same pc I was using before and installed all essential software that I was using before. I installed few days back it worked fine, but right now SDK not working inside eclipse.

Sdk/Avd manager works fine outside but it is not showing anything under Eclipse under windows tab.  When I go to Preference there is also no Android tab.  All software are 32bit and the window version I am using is also 32bit.  I tried everything I could.  I am not a newbie programmer.

1. Installed Windows again.
2. I Downloaded everything New and up to date to make sure no compatibility issue.
3. I reinstalled Sdk to make sure there is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
Eclipse > Help > Software Updates
```

And update your version of the Android Eclipse Plugin

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

The download site is:

```
 https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not installed ADT first download it then in Eclipse  Help->Install New software then install it and restart the Eclipse and use it