# Android SDK wont't be launched from eclipse

Tags: java, android, windows, eclipse, sdk

I came to my home after a while and I found out my eclipse won't launch the Android SDK (it will launch the loading bar but then nothing pops) , I tried everything I think,

- upgrade java & also copy its program files to another location and change system Variables
  (for certainty)
- change find_java.bat in the sdk folder
- download and install the adt-bundle-windows again
- copy the SDK Manager.exe in the SDK folder

I tried of course to open SDK Manager.exe alone and it won't open unless I run it as an admin. So I changed to run always as admin still nothing at eclipse running, still the same. I see at the properties security tab of the Android SDK everything checked . Could you please find me a solution to open SDK Manager.exe from eclipse , thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**

Also to note that the eclipse Console has this :

[image]

Comment: did you get any error message?

Comment: Please visit [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22215958/3330969), You are also in same boat.

Comment: @Shriram no I don't get any error message

Comment: @Kedarnath Not fully tested yet but my AVD is working fine

Comment: @Kerdarnath Yup , AVD also doesn't launch you're wright , hoping for a solution

Answer (score 2):

try updating the ADT from eclipse:
You can here [Android SDK not Working inside Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593940/android-sdk-not-working-inside-eclipse).

Steps:
Eclipse > Help > Software Updates
And update your version of the Android Eclipse Plugin

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

The download site is:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

If you are opening it in eclipse, then provide correct path in Windows -> Preferences ->Android-> SDK location bar - put your C:\Path\to\Android\android-sdk

Comment: I have two instances of the android eclipse each one with different SDK Manager.exe neither of them won't open it will just show the status bar

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with the privileges and I had to run every .exe as admin.Format my pc was the solution to me and everything since then run like a charm.I think it's not eclipse's problem for the most part I think.